# Can an uncountable set be chopped up into singletons using countably many "slices"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable set. Can we find a countable family of subsets of $X$, $(A_i)$, such that for every $x\in X$:

$$\bigcap \{ A_i | x\in A_i \} = \{x\}$$

If you think of each $A_i$ as being a kind of "chop", where we cut out a section of $X$ with a cookie cutter, we're saying that after countably many chops we've completely chopped $X$ up into singletons.

I sort of doubt the answer depends on $|X|$, but if it does, what is the largest cardinal of $X$ such that this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $\mathcal A$ your set of subsets. As it's been already pointed out, the image of the map $\bigcap:\mathcal P(\mathcal A)\to\mathcal P(X)$ contains the singletons, therefore $\lvert X\rvert\le \lvert\mathcal P(\mathcal A)\rvert\le \beth_1$.

If $\lvert X\rvert\le \beth_1$, then without loss of generality $X\subseteq \Bbb R$. Therefore it can be given a structure of second-countable metric space and any countable base $\mathcal A$ works.

Comment: So to be more explicit, if $X\subseteq\mathbb R$, let $\mathcal A$ be the set of open intervals with rational endpoints, or rather their intersections with $X$. Obviously this works since we can take arbitrarily small intervals around $X$. If we set $X=\mathbb R$, that gives us probably the simplest example of such a construction.

Answer (score 0):

$x \mapsto \{i: x \in A_i\}$ is  one-to-one map from $x$ into the power set of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: So this is to say that it works for $\mathfrak c = |2^\mathbb{N}|$ but cannot work for larger cardinals, I suppose? I would probably like to make the claim clear before I try to prove it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: By one-to-one I suppose you mean injective, not bijective... basically you're saying that the "signature" of any $x$ in the sense of the specification of which $A_i$ it belongs to acts as a unique binary encoding of $x$. So yes, $|X|\leq|\mathbb R|$.

Comment: @JackM I thought one-to-one, into,onto etc are universally accepted Mathematical terms.